Purpose of burn permit?
In Ontario, Canada, some municipalities require property owners to acquire a permit for open-air fires, such as when cleaning up excess yard waste and fallen trees.
From the municipality’s perspective, what is the main reason they require a permit? What problem does it solve?

Interesting question, but not sure if it fits on TGO or rather on [Politics.SE].

Just guessing: Prevent bush fires?

Or to try to reduce burning (too small, to wet), mainly on residential areas, where smoke may invade other properties. Outdoor managing guidelines changes with time (on not so far past, nobody would think to burn trees or leaves: you need them, then as fire prevention and disease prevention, now it seems it is not so useful on both cases, in future, who know?).

CO² reductions? Smog reduction?There are already cities in Europe asking the residents not to burn wood in their fireplace on days with mist.

Where my parents live in Oregon it is all about the local fire departments analysis of wildfire hazard. Burning is limited to specific months of the year, and they will reject permits if the fire hazard is high even in a nominally 'wet' period. So, the problem solved is burning down the forest as a byproduct of burning your trash.

Burn permits can serve different purposes in different locations. The first and most important purpose is that they are not always granted when requested. You have to ask. People might say no. For example, where I live no permits are issued in April. There are various criteria you have to meet to get one. People generally obey the rules, so if the rules say "you need a permit" and when you try to get one you have to do something you weren't planning to do, or wait a few weeks, or whatever, probably that's what you'll do. Or you may be told that a permit can't be issued for your address because there are too many people nearby or whatever. Again assuming you're a rules-follower, this will reduce danger and nuisance to your neighbours.
The stuff that might or might not apply include:

the fire department knows you're burning something at your address, so they won't panic if someone calls in that they smell or see smoke; though of course they'll still reply if you call saying that your fire is out of control
they may charge for the permits, so that's revenue
it's an opportunity to educate you about smart burning and remind you of the rules

Finally, people are more likely to comply with "you can only do this if you meet these conditions" (even when those conditions are essentially impossible to comply with) than with "you can't do this."

Air quality may also be a consideration.

@JonCuster, air quality is more often managed through a blanket ban than through the case-by-case analysis of a permit system.

@Mark It would be reasonable to expect a limit on simultaneous burns in order to help moderate air quality.

The education piece is important. Instead of trying to educate the whole community on all of the rules, they can just focus on "you need to get a burn permit" and let the permitting process take care of providing more specific education to the people doing the burning at the time they plan to burn, when it's more likely to be effective and remembered. And if that fails, there's a very clear record of "you agreed to A, B, and C last week but you didn't do them" that they can go after you with.

Presumably it also encourages people to plan and prepare for their burn, rather than deciding to light up their waste pile on a saturday afternoon after a couple of beers...

In one place I'm familiar with, Corvallis Oregon, a free Outdoor Burning Permit is required through the Corvallis Rural Fire District. The very top part of the applications states:

Designation of burn days is based upon daily environmental conditions. Between October 1 and June 15, the Oregon Department of Forestry determines whether burning will be recommended. Between June 16 and September 30, the Oregon Department of Agriculture makes that determination.

The Department of Forestry is more concerned about forest fire conditions during the normally wet season, the Department of Agriculture is more concerned about air quality (yes, particularly in the Willamette Valley burning of fields used to fill the valley with smoke in the late summer).
Besides stating a day (and time frame) and the property address, the rest of the form (link at Corvallis city site, one needs to read the handout from the State of Oregon Department of Environmental Quality before getting to the permit itself) is a bunch of checkboxes acknowledging all the requirements one has to follow. This includes checking the day of your permit if burning is allowed in the area that particular day.
It is free, so revenue is not the issue. The fire department proper does not handle determination of allowed burn days, that is handled by the state. Whether a burn day is allowed or not is a combination of forest fire danger and air quality considerations. The purpose of the permit seems more to be to make sure that the landowner understands (or at least checks the boxes saying they understand) all the requirements to safely burn, and all the various fines they may accumulate if they don't do the right things.

I am a fire warden in Queensland, Australia where a Permit to Burn is required for any fire more than 2m in any dimension.
There are a few reasons, some of which have been covered:

one of the conditions of burns is that the holder must notify the fire dept when they are about to light up.  As @Kate Gregory says, it is to avoid unnecessary well intentioned false alarms.
Another condition is that neighbours must be advised, this can help prevent 1.
Depending on conditions, the location or some other criteria, a permit may be refused.  So a permit can help prevent people doing something stupid - it doesn't.
It makes people think about what they are about to do, especially when I put the wind up them reminding them that they are responsible for everything should the fire get away - it happens at least once a year.

It also gives me the opportunity to engage with our community and offer advice about having a fire plan, how to reduce the risk to their property or whatever.  It is a volunteer position that takes up some time as I have to visit each applicant, but in the long run, it is worth it.
[UPDATE] Ironically, a day after posting this I received an SMS that tomorrow is going to be high fire danger with 35C 20%RH and 45kph wind, so all fire permits are on hold.

I think there are some words missing at the end of point 3.

@PMF Nope, it was an attempt at "humour" that permits don't prevent people doing something stupid :o)
